# Unable to put null values in JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to pass parameter to api using JSON.

```
class Sample
{ ...
   String token;
...

void method()
{ ...
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put(KEY_TOKEN,token);
    params.put(KEY_DATE,date);

    Log.e("params ",params+"");


      ...  }
```

I get the value of params as `{"date":"2017-06-19"}` but token is seen nowhere.
I have not initialized token and its value is null as its an instance variable. So is it something that uninitialized value are not included?

Comment: you can check, no? token=null

Comment: just need to ask about uninitialized values

Comment: @aish: Since `token` is of type `String` and it's an instance member, it has the default value `null`, so it comes to the same thing.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Right there in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), in the first paragraph:

> Values may not be `null`, `NaN`s, infinities, or of any type not listed here.

So yes, it is *"...something that `null` values are not included..."* *(edit: that was a quote from your original question; your updated question changes it to "uninitialized values" but the default value of an object reference is `null`, so...)*

It's a "feature" of that class, though; [JSON](http://json.org) itself understands `null` just fine. Further down in the documentation it says you use a "sentinal value," [`NULL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL), to represent `null`. Which seems...odd. There's a note about it:

> **Warning**: this class represents `null` in two incompatible ways: the standard Java `null` reference, and the sentinel value `NULL`. In particular, calling `put(name, null)` removes the named entry from the object but `put(name, JSONObject.NULL)` stores an entry whose value is `JSONObject.NULL`.

So:

```
params.put(KEY_TOKEN, token == null ? JSONObject.NULL : token);
```

Comment: but the value of that string object is null so it should understand it. if not than must throw an error

Comment: @aish: Talk to the designers of `JSONObject`. They're the ones who decided to have it behave this way. The good news is there *is* a way to get that `null` in there, you just have to do it in a non-standard way. Which seems, frankly, silly, but I don't know all the design constraints they were working under.

Comment: Having anything of value null is removed from JSON because it is understood to be not set and therefore unrequired. Therefore, it is removed from JSON string reducing load during network transport

Comment: @BhalchandraSW: That should be a `remove` operation, not a `put` operation. Not handling `null` in a normal, unsurprising way is just weird. :-)

Comment: Thanks, with this solution I still get the key sent over the wire, the Java's null would (just like you stated) remove the key.

Comment: And also jsonObject.optString(key) returns the String "null" instead of an actual null. Worst json implementation I've ever seen.

Answer (score 14):

According to [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), JSON treats the `null` symbol as a valid value.

The catch is that JSON `null` is the representation for the Javascript `null` value.  By contrast, the Java version of `null` is (according to the experts) more closely aligned with Javascript's `undefined` value.

The original author of the `org.json` library decided that `JSONObject` should treat JSON `null` in a way that is consistent with the Javascript semantics.  Hence it is represented (in Java) as `JSONObject.NULL` ... which is not equal to `null`.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by creating the null JSON value using a string representation to stuff the null value into the object. Clearly a hack, but it works.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"keyword\": null}");
System.out.println(obj); // {"keyword": null}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by creating a class that extends `JSONObject` and overriding the method `put` to use `JSONObject.NULL` when the passed object is `null`

```java
public class ObjectJSON extends JSONObject {
    public JSONObject put(String key, Object value) throws JSONException {
        return super.put(key, value == null ? JSONObject.NULL : value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldnt use the solution as it is as i could not extend the JSONObject class from net.sf.json.JSONObject as the class is final. What i did instead was to create a utility method                    i.e.    public static Object getJSONObjectValue(Object value)  {
  return value == null ? "null" : value;
 }                  then call this method whenever i call the put method of the JSONObject class like this ... jsonObject.put("key", Utility.getJSONObjectValue( objectValue ));

Answer (score 1):

Json itself accpets null but JSONOBJECT class does not.Hence, you are not able to do that. Also Try using jackson/gson for json and object mapping instead. If you need help with it, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this "feature" and created this project https://github.com/leonardofel/JSON-java-put-null-fix

making the following code bellow possible:

```java
JSONObject j = new JSONObject().put("myPreciousNull", null);
System.out.println(j.toString());
```

prints:

```json
{"myPreciousNull":null}
```